# simple multiple reallocation of double char pointer c

Tags: c, pointers, char, realloc

Im trying to reallocate a double char pointer dynamicly in a larger program and im always getting that error "realloc(): invalid next size", so i wrote a smaller test to show u guy my exact problem:

my little test:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char **buf = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        buf[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
        strcpy(buf[i], "hallo");
        printf("%s\n", buf[i]);
        if( (realloc(buf, sizeof(char*) * (i+1))) == NULL) exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is always crashing at the 4th reallocation with the full error message:

```
Error in `./myTest': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001cb2010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f450a4a97e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x834aa)[0x7f450a4b54aa]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x179)[0x7f450a4b6839]
./myTest[0x40069c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f450a452830]
./myTest[0x400529]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 663159                             
/home/qbongo/BS-PK-2017/10_pk/myTest
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 663159                             
/home/qbongo/BS-PK-2017/10_pk/myTest
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 663159                             
/home/qbongo/BS-PK-2017/10_pk/myTest
01cb2000-01cd3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f4504000000-7f4504021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4504021000-7f4508000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f450a21c000-7f450a232000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 398530                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f450a232000-7f450a431000 ---p 00016000 08:01 398530                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f450a431000-7f450a432000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 398530                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f450a432000-7f450a5f2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394742                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f450a5f2000-7f450a7f2000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 394742                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f450a7f2000-7f450a7f6000 r--p 001c0000 08:01 394742                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f450a7f6000-7f450a7f8000 rw-p 001c4000 08:01 394742                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f450a7f8000-7f450a7fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f450a7fc000-7f450a822000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393312                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f450aa07000-7f450aa0a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f450aa20000-7f450aa21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f450aa21000-7f450aa22000 r--p 00025000 08:01 393312                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f450aa22000-7f450aa23000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 393312                     
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f450aa23000-7f450aa24000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffcc108f000-7ffcc10b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffcc1149000-7ffcc114b000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffcc114b000-7ffcc114d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  
[vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 errors in your code.

1. You're not storing in `buf` the new address returned by `realloc`. When the new space required is not available in place, `realloc` allocates a new space somewhere else in memory.
2. Your loop starts at `i = 0`, therefor the first time you reach `realloc`, you're expected to allocate two elements: `i+2` instead of `i+1`

Comment: thank u very much, this solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

By invoking `char **buf = malloc(sizeof(char*));` you are allocating just a single pointer, not an array of them.

```
const size_t items_count = 20;
char **buf = malloc(sizeof(char*) * items_count);
for(int i = 0; i < items_count; i++){
    buf[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6); // now we won't access array out of bounds here
// no need to realloc
```

Comment: But he reallocates on each iteration. I don't think this code is the actual code, but just an example to show at which iteration `realloc` fails.

Comment: @Groo Realoc code is wrong (it will realoc the same amount of bytes) and rather pointless when array size is known in advance.

Comment: yes, i want to invoke the next pointer of the array with the line

    if( (realloc(buf, sizeof(char*) * (i+1))) == NULL) exit(-1);

Comment: @Qbongo What do you mean by "invoke the next pointer of the array"?

Comment: @Groo you are totally right, its just an example to point out the issue

Comment: @VTT  the plan is to allocate the next pointer of the next string right befor its needed. but its crashing always at the 4th reallocation

Comment: @Qbongo But you already know required array size, reallocating array on each iteration would be inefficient.

Comment: @VTT:  This isn't OP's actual code, the length most likely isn't known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be:

```
buf = realloc(buf, sizeof(char*) * (i+2));
```

1. Your code is simply throwing away the result of `realloc`.
2. You need to allocate `(i+2)` if you are doing it at the end of the iteration.

I am presuming this isn't your actual code, but it would make more sense to move `realloc` to the top of the loop (check the [first example for `realloc` on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)), something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    buf = realloc(buf, sizeof(char*) * (i+1));
    if (buf == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    ...
}
```

**(update)**

According to @coderredoc's comments below, although `exit` will free all memory associated with the process, keep in mind that good programming practice would be to free the previously allocated pointer, in case `realloc` fails:

```
char **buf = malloc(sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    // try to realloc
    {
        char ** larger = realloc(buf, sizeof(char*) * (i + 1));
        if (larger) 
        {
            buf = larger;
        }
        else 
        {
            // realloc failed, we might need to free individual items
            // if we are not going to use them anymore
            for (int k = 0; k < (i - 1); k++) free(buf[k]);

            // we should free previous buff also
            free(buff);

            // we can exit, or break the loop, or whatever
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    // do stuff here
    ...
}
```

Comment: @coderredoc: I updated the answer with your comments anyway, someone will find these details useful, thanks!